# Source folder names with tilde excluded from build on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Some of my source folder names end with tilde symbol (`e.g. MyCode~`) and I just realized these folders are excluded from the build on Android Studio. They won't even show up on the source list.

When I rename the source folders to be without tilde and restart the project, I could see the source folders again.

Is this intentionally designed like this in Android Studio?
Is there a way to disable excluding the tilde folders? I also use Xcode and Visual Studio but only Android Studio seems to exclude these folders.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of achieving what you want.. AS has some name conventions for its files.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos So do you suggest just getting rid of tilde from source folder names?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any benefit using that special character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio by default is set up to ignore any file/folder name that ends with tilde. Apart from tilde there are some other pre-defined formats. However, this is configurable.

Go to File-> Settings -> Editor -> File Types (In Windows, should be similar place in Mac also) and look for Ignored files and folders at the bottom. You will see something like this:

*.hprof;*.pyc;*.pyo;*.rbc;*.yarb;*~;.DS_Store;.git;.hg;.svn;CVS;__pycache__;_svn;vssver.scc;vssver2.scc;

I have never changed this config, so I guess this is the default one set by Android Studio. Here you can see a pattern ***~**

Any file or folder name that matches these (in your case, having a tilde at the end of a folder name) is automatically ignored by Android Studio. If you try to create a new folder or file with tilde at the end, studio will show the error there itself.

However, good news is, these expressions can be changed. For example, you can remove ***~** from the ignored list and your directories with a tilde at the end will be accepted in Android studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you!. Is this setting saved per solution or will it apply to all solutions/projects in the future?

Comment: This setting is applicable to Android Studio installation. Hence any project opened in future with this changed configuration in android studio will be covered automatically